# API + restart the services that restart is required

Tags: hadoop, ambari

after adding new parameter and value to the ambari cluster , we need to restart the service to take affect

from ambari GUI restart the service is required , and we can see that because restart button is colored with orange

so my question is

we need API command that restart only the services that restart is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to restart all relevant services ( that need's restart )  the following syntax is the answer

```
curl  -u admin:admin -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X POST  -d '{"RequestInfo":{"command":"RESTART","context":"Restart all required services","operation_level":"host_component"},"Requests/resource_filters":[{"hosts_predicate":"HostRoles/stale_configs=true"}]}' http://amb25101.example.com:8080/api/v1/clusters/plain_ambari/requests
```